# Ajax parse error. Ajax returning error after success. Php working fine but the response is still in error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax parse error. Ajax returning error after success. PHP working fine but the response is still in error. The code works fine with curl but
not with xml. I'm not a pro in xml but the API return xml response so I  am forced to use xml  I can't identify the error SMS is being sent and database is successfully updated but the ajax is not properly working. Hope I have explained enough

Here is the ajax code from where the form data is being sent

```
$.ajax({
                                                                
data:$('form#candidateForm').serialize(),
type:"POST",
url:"php-modules/registeration.php",
success:function(msg){
alert(typeof msg);
if(typeof msg =='object'){
$("#otpc_id").val(msg.c_id);
jQuery('.careerfy-modal').removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade');                                                                       jQuery('body').removeClass('careerfy-modal-active');                                                                         jobsearch_modal_popup_open("otpVerification");
}
else{
alert(msg);
}     
},
error: function(request, error){
console.log(arguments);
alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
alert("Error connecting to file");
 }
 });
```

php code that after successfullt inserts data in the database send the otp message and returns xml response

```
//OTP SMS Variables 
               $message='Your OTP Code '.$rand_no.'.';

               // OTP FUNCTION
               $sessionKey=getSessionId();
               $ph_number=$GLOBALS['c_phone'];
               $phone = preg_replace('/[^\dxX]/', '', $ph_number);

               $send = sendSmsMessage($message,$phone,'OEC-GoP',$sessionKey );
               //echo "1";
               //IF SUCCESSFULLY MESSAGE IS SENT 
               if($send){
                echo $send;
                $candidate_id = array("c_id"=>"$last_id");
                header("Content-Type: application/json");
                echo json_encode($candidate_id);
               }else{
                echo "measageNotSent";
               }
```

xml code

```
function sendSmsMessage($messageText,$toNumbersCsv,$mask,$sessionKey)
{
global $planetbeyondApiSendSmsUrl;
$sessionKey=getSessionId();
$url=str_replace("#message_text#",urlencode($messageText),$planetbeyondApiSendSmsUrl);
$url=str_replace("#to_number_csv#",$toNumbersCsv,$url);
$url=str_replace("#from_number#",$fromNumber,$url);
$urlWithSessionKey=str_replace("#session_id#",$sessionKey,$url);
if($mask!=null)
{
$urlWithSessionKey = $urlWithSessionKey . "&mask=" . $mask;
}
$xml=sendApiCall($urlWithSessionKey);
return $xml->data;
}
/**
 Sends Http request to api
*/
function sendApiCall($url)
{
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

 if($xml && !empty($xml->response))
 {
return $xml;
}
return "";
}
function getSessionId()
{
global $userName,$password,$planetbeyondApiUrl;
$url=str_replace("#username#",$userName,$planetbeyondApiUrl);
$url=str_replace("#password#",$password,$url);
$response = sendApiCall ($url);
 if($response && substr($response->response,0,5)!=="Error")
 {
return $response->data;
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve here? The parser is confused because you first print some XML with `echo $send;` and then you either print some JSON with `echo json_encode($candidate_id);` or print out a literal string with `echo "measageNotSent";`. Either way, what you end up with is a combined result that AJAX can't make sense of. From what I can tell, just removing `echo $send;` would solve your issue, as it seems you're not actually looking to do anything with the XML response.

Comment: @El_Vanja I were using `echo $send` to check whether there is an issue regarding the xml file if its sending some data or not i forgot to comment it in here. Everything is working perfectly i am receiving an SMS but the problem occurs when the thing turns back to my js file where ajax checks  for success or error its giving me the parseerror and not opening the intented bootstrap modal

Comment: `parseerror` means it's unable to parse the response.  So your response is *not* **pure json**.  What *is* the *exact* response?  Have you checked the network tab to see **exactly** what is being returned, not what you think your code may have returned

Comment: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at parse in console

Comment: Yes, you **clearly** have either html or xml being output - check the *actual* output via browser (F12) network tab/tools.

Comment: If this happens even after commenting `echo $send;`, my bet is PHP is reporting a notice or warning.

Comment: `$url=str_replace("#from_number#",$fromNumber,$url);` The problem was occurring because of this code there wasn't any fromnumber  variable, I commented this and everything is working fine now this was the sample code provided by the gateway service. All the time I was worrying about there was some error in my code while it was in the provided API

Answer (score 0):

The Error occurred due to fromNumber Variable was not set. So the php was attaching the Error with the Json code removing that extra line of code helped and the code is working fine.
`// $url=str_replace("#from_number#",$fromNumber,$url);`